# Updating a question with new findings whilst keeping it tidy and clear

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, etiquette

I tend to write detailed questions about a problem that occurs in a general situation. For instance, recently I stumbled [upon an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55835323/processing-large-files-in-chunks-inconsistent-seek-with-readline) where I want to read chunks of data quickly (to be used in a multiprocessing environment) by retrieving the file pointers of these chunks. The details are not important here, but I *do* do my best to make the general scenario as well as the specific problem as clear as possible. To this end I provide my thoughts as texts, the code that I have tried out, and often also testing data. This makes my main post already quite long. I always fear that the length of my posts will scare away readers, so I try to keep it to the point.

When I have posted a question, I am often continuously working on it afterwards. This means that I frequently make new discoveries that I think are relevant and useful for other readers. In practice this means that I have to add a few new paragraphs as well as a bunch of code - making the question even more scary at first sight.

Since many questions can often be solved in numerous ways, I tend to only keep the most favourable approach in my post. Or when I find out that one of my proposed ideas actually has fundamental flaws in it, I delete it from the post. I do not wish to keep adding information and findings, and annotating some with a warning 'I have found that this approach does not work, so please ignore.' as that does not seem to help anyone.

Still, it happens that someone reads part of my post and starts writing an answer, but in the meantime I found that my thoughts are flawed, so I delete it from the post. The answerer then replies to something that is not in the post any more, and frequently - if I was correct - their solution does not work anyway, as the reason that I deleted my idea in the first place was because there was a fundamental flaw in it. This happened in my most recent post, where someone got angry with me because I had edited out the part of the question they referred to. However, I only removed this part from the question because it contained a large assumption that did not hold (i.e. it turns out that byte sequences can still be chopped up initially), so the answerer's answer could never work.

Now, to get to my question: I understand this person's frustration - even though I don't think my changes warrant a downvote. I had added information to my main post, and afterwards removed it. They had worked on a solution with that information (even though they did not check their solution, otherwise they would have found that it did not suffice). In the end I did re-add the information that the user replied to, but nevertheless they did delete their answer. So **what is the best thing to do here**: keep all added information, even if further research finds that some of it cannot be used? Delete everything that is not relevant anymore? Of particular importance is the length of the post; new findings may make a post challenging to read through, especially if some parts are marked as not relevant. When adding all new found insights, the question might not invite users to read the whole thing.

Comment: I would suggest waiting until you're actually blocked (i.e., the process of trial and error has settled down to a dull roar) before asking a question. If you're finding yourself editing questions that often, your question may not be ready for posting. Remember, Stack Overflow was not created to host debugging sessions or discussions (except on Meta); it's meant for questions and answers.

Comment: I tend to agree with what Heretic Monkey said. I share your pain here of being someone who writes long, detailed posts, ensuring that I include a complete description of the motivation, what I have tried unsuccessfully, and sometimes even suggest approaches that appear promising to me. However, I’ve never had the problem you describe of needing to continually modify my question after posting it. I don’t even *ask* the question until I’ve exhausted my own debugging avenues and investigations, so there’s nothing left to change. That said, the linked question looks good to me in present form.

Comment: I understand what you both mean, but I do wait until I am really struck. When I have tried anything I can think of at a given time, I post the question. But since these problems are part of my job (I often need to solve the issue before I can continue other work), I tend to post the question when I'm stuck and then start working on something trivial. But then I get a new insight, or a new idea that I hadn't thought of before. So it is hard if not impossible for me to tell when I have 'tried everything I could' because sometimes you just get some new ideas.

Comment: This is just my impression, so take that for what it's worth, but after looking over some of your questions, it seems like you like to use Stack Overflow as your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Comment: @BramVanroy That can of course happen, but your question describes a scenario in which you're "continuously working on it afterwards", which is something else.

Comment: Are you certain that the ideas aren't coming to you while you write the post? I *frequently* find myself dropping the post to go try an idea or test some theory or confirm some assumption while I'm writing. Often times, I end up rewriting most of the post or even not posting at all.